# Sending Auto text message to caller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app deals with phone calls.I want to send auto text messages (similar to callwaiting) to the caller when the line is busy or holding another call.... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of application isn't possible with the default iOS SDK - you can neither send text messages, or indeed detect when a phone call is happening. Are you targeting jailbroken devices only?

Comment: In which case, I'm afraid you can't target iOS devices (unless by phone call you mean "VOIP calls that my app is making" and by text messages you mean "I will send them through a 3rd party server"). You could, in principle, write this type of application for Android.

Comment: Ya my calls will be through Voice Over IP.But i don't have any idea about sending text messages..